# How to build APK with no sound null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I can run an app in release mode on my phone with passing flag `--no-sound-null-safety --release`, but
neither `flutter build apk --enable-experiment=non-nullable`
nor `flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety`
nor `flutter build apk --enable-experiment=non-nullable --no-sound-null-safety`
will work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was only necessary to use additional comment `// @dart=2.9` before all imports in `main.dart` so it could run without any flags

So `main.dart` should look like this:

```dart
// @dart=2.9
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import '../init.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  GestureBinding.instance?.resamplingEnabled = true;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Any other `.dart` files don't require annotating them

P.S. make sure you updated `pubspec.yaml` for using Dart 2.12:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-0.0 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: It does not fixes the problem, as it only states that the file does not supports null safety.

Comment: I don'y see any problem as `main.dart` should be used only as an entry point such as `runApp(MyApp())` and actual `MyApp()` widget could be in another file

Comment: But this other file would still have the problem. If it uses null-safety

Comment: Nope. My full project uses null-safety and only `main.dart` doesn't and everything works as expected

Comment: Are you sure? Because the doc say otherwise : 'Add a language version comment to the top of any Dart files that you don’t want to consider during your current migration:'
So, other file would still be checked for null safety

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because otherwise I wouldn't mark it as an answer. Before annotating `flutter build apk` produced a lot of errors related to null checks

Comment: // @dart=2.9 marks the whole file to be used with Dart 2.9. If only a few of the libraries used as imports are nullable, but the rest of the file has been adjusted for null safety (and uses e.g. the nullability character ?), this won't work.

Comment: @TinMan Everything works if you put everything out of `main.dart` and leave it with only `runApp()` function

Comment: Not working for 2022 with Flutter 2.10.0

Answer (score 59):

**Just do this on your terminal**

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

**Or**

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: it did not works when the flutter version is 2.2.x when build ios pakcage.@Adam Musa

Comment: In flutter 2.x null safety is enabled by default. So to solve this you have to downgrade the sdk version of dart to 2.7.x. And you change the way of coding when you bring your sdk back to 2.7.x because it does not support the philosophy of sdk> = 2.10.x

Answer (score 9):

we can try this,

```
 flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

or by adding in main.dart , 1st Line

```
 // @dart=2.9
```

Answer (score 2):

flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety

Answer (score 0):

If You are facing **no sound null safety** problem then follow 3 Steps.

1. **// @2.9** in the top and remove the parameter from **Const app_name();**
2. 2nd solution is run **--no-sound-null-safety** in the terminal
3. Edit your Configure File and write in ***Additional run args:-* --no-sound-null-safety**

See these images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yenig.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzzwb.png).