# Generate App Bundle with --no-sound-null-safety Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, bundle, dart-null-safety

I am trying to generate the App Bundle via Android studio (Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK), and I am running into an error when building a bundle.

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety
```

Is there a way that I can add the argument `--no-sound-null-safety`, similar to what you can do in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Run

```dart
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590827/6618622)

Comment: I know this command, but this isn't what I was asking for. Is there a way to add that argument within android studio?

Answer (score 1):

```
    run:
flutter build appbundle --no-sound-null-safety
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable sound null safety using the --no-sound-null-safety flag to the dart or flutter command:

```
 dart --no-sound-null-safety run
 flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

Alternatively, set the language version in the entrypoint — the file that contains main() function — to 2.9

```
// @dart=2.9
import 'src/my_app.dart';

main() {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
flutter build appbundle --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

to build a app bundle with no sound null safety use this command

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better.

Comment: to build a app bundle with no sound null safety use this command

Comment: Hi, the purpose of my comment was for you to edit your answer and expand it.  Else the community bot may delete it.