# seems no-sound-null-safety parameter not work in flutter 2.2.1

Tags: flutter

I am upgrade my flutter to version 2.2.1, but it seems `--no-sound-null-safety` no longer avaliable when build the ios package. I am build the project using this command:

```
~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --no-sound-null-safety
```

but the output still tell me some package did not support null safety:

```
Changing current working directory to: /Users/dolphin/source/cruise-open
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.earth.dolphin for device (ios-release)...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           36.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    2 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
    don't support null safety:

     - package:state_notifier
     - package:fish_redux
     - package:flutter_icons

    For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Removed stale file
    

Encountered error while building for device.
```

is there any solution with this problem? I am search from flutter issue but no one confirm this problem(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84199), is it a bug of new version?(Because I am using this command works fine until I upgrade to version 2.2.1). is there other way to pass `no-sound-null-safety` parameter? I have tried many version and found some version works fine, some version did not works. Maybe a flutter bug.

- flutter 2.0.1 works
- flutter 2.0.3 works
- flutter 2.0.6 works
- flutter 2.2.0 not works
- flutter 2.2.1 not works
- flutter 2.2.2 not works
- flutter 2.2.3 not works

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504664/how-to-build-apk-with-no-sound-null-safety

Comment: I have already read this question, still could not fix my problem. I have already add the `--no-sound-null-safety` parameter in command!!! @ghostdeathrider by the way, the android comand works fine, but the ios did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem a bug, will fixed next release:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/84372