# How to build with a package who doesn't migrate to null safety?

Tags: flutter

I want to upgrade my flutter version with null safety but some packages didn't migrate.

For example flutter_timeline / capture and share / flutter_dialogflow  they did not migrate to null safety

What happen if I upgrade flutter with package not null safety ?

can I still build and release app on store or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` command to run a project that depends on packages or parts with no sound-null safety yet.

Comment: but possible to build a release with that ?

Comment: yes, you can use flutter build --no-sound-null-safety too

Comment: there is a similar thread about this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504664/how-to-build-apk-with-no-sound-null-safety

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make a release if you upgrade to null safety. You need to either replace the packages or update them yourself