# Flutter APK Errors while build apk command running?

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I have a flutter app and its working fine in debug mode but when i run flutter build apk command for android apk it shows the following error.
The error is cannot run with sound null safety.
**Error:**

```
 C:\Users\RAILO\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:flutter_swiper
 - package:flutter_page_indicator
 - package:transformer_page_view

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: build without null safety because these 3 libs are not updated to null-safety dart version.

Comment: how can I build without null safety.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504664/how-to-build-apk-with-no-sound-null-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line on top of main.dart

// @dart=2.9

**then run $flutter clean && flutter pub  get**

Answer (score 1):

you can try this command also.

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```